# flutter_screenutil not working ,,,problem in builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using `flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2`
and build_runner: ^2.0.4
after running the build runner
there is error in the builder of screenutlils

[image: here is the picture]

Comment: try this code  "flutter clean cache" in terminal or downgrade screenutil version and build_runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use ScreenUtilInit like this

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // In first method you only need to wrap [MaterialApp] with [ScreenUtilInit] and that's it
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      builder: (_, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Test',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.sp)),
          ),
          home: child,
        );
      },
      child: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here `ScreenUtilInit` builder require context and child

```dart
  builder: (context , child) { //this
```

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScreenUtilInit(
    builder: (context, child) {
      return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [],
        child: Text("AA"),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried this, error red line goes ,, but the code still does not work

Comment: do a `flutter clean` and then restart the ide and build the app, if you face new issue this might be coming from different section